# Can EzPDF library for php add password encryption to generated PDFs

Tags: php, pdf

Pretty much as in the title, can't find much in the way of an answer to this anywhere. I need to create some pdfs using a template background that has live data injected to it through PHP. I need the final pdf that gets pushed to the user to be password encrypted, does EzPDF support this?

Answer (score 0):

Your title shows **`ExPDF`** and you are asking **does `EzPDF` support this** am not sure if any of them supports such but i would recommend you use  [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/) has PDF password protection and public key encryption

Example

```
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

//Password Protection (SetProtection($permissions=array('print', 'copy'), $user_pass='', $owner_pass=null, $mode=0, $pubkeys=null);) 
$pdf->SetProtection(array('print', 'copy'), $user_pass, $owner_pass, $mode, null);


//Example With Public Keys 

$pdf->SetProtection(array('print', 'copy'), $user_pass, $owner_pass, $mode, array(array('c' => 'file://../tcpdf.crt', 'p' => array('print'))));
```